# Spring data JPA - return an Object from a Group Query

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i would like to know hot to return an object from a Group by query.

I have this query in my repository interface

```
@Query(value = "SELECT data, objectId, stampo, min(rendimento) as rendimento from rendimenti where objectId=:objectId "
            + "and stampo=:mold group By data, objectId, stampo order by data DESC LIMIT 0,1", nativeQuery = true)
    Wrapper findByObjectAndMold(@Param("objectId") int objecId, @Param("mold") String mold);
```

This query should return a single Object (or none), running it on the DB works.
I created a Wrapper object to take the result

```
public class Wrapper {

    @Column(name="rendimento")
    private Performance performance;

    private int objectId;

    @Column(name="stampo")
    private String mold;

    @Column(name="data")
    private Date date;

//getters and setters
}
```

I'm getting this exception

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown entity: javax.persistence.Tuple; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: javax.persistence.Tuple] with root cause

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: javax.persistence.Tuple
```

So i think the query cannot be mapped to my wrapper...

So i changed the query method in this way

```
@Query(value = "SELECT data, objectId, stampo, min(rendimento) as rendimento from rendimenti where objectId=:objectId "
            + "and stampo=:mold group By data, objectId, stampo order by data DESC LIMIT 0,1", nativeQuery = true)
    Object[] findByObjectAndMold(@Param("objectId") int objecId, @Param("mold") String mold);
```

and then i tried to take the Array elements

```
Object[] o = repository(object.getObjectId(), mold);
        logger.debug("Wrapper is " + o.toString());
        if(o != null){
            Date date = (Date) o[0];
            logger.debug("La data è : " + date);
            float performance = (float) o[3];
```

but, i'm getting a casting error..

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Date
```

Which is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Are these tables all JPA entities and is it possible for you to use JPQL?

Comment: The wrapper is not an entity but the table of the query is an entity and yes i can use JPQL

Comment: OK. I will soon provide an answer w/o entities. And if you can make Wrapper also entity then there is one easier option also. Java8/java7?

Comment: You use Java8 then? Wait a sec before you start coding. There is another solution coming also.

Comment: Ok i’ll wait! Thanks, but look that i’m not returning a list of array but only one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First solution for manipulating `Object[]`

if your tables or Wrapper are not `Entities` and/or you cannot use `JPQL` then create a constructor in wrapper class that takes all need parameters as `Object`s. It is good idea to put put default non-arg constructor also because some other stuff might need it.

```
public Wrapper(Object o1, Object o2 ... ) { //means NOT varargs but as 
                                            //many args you need, all as objects
   this.performance = (Performance)o1;
   this.id = (Integer)o2;
   ...
}
```

Then if using `Java8` it easy to convert with `Stream` using your original Object[].

```
List<Wrapper> wrappers = Arrays.stream(yourObjectArray)
   .map( arr -> new Wrapper(arr[0], arr[1], ...)) // the rs possible args
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Just check that args in costructor are in the same order as fetched by query to `Object[]`. Of course you can also change order inside `.map()` but it only will mess things up in my opinion.

#### Second solution use JPA `NEW`

requires that all related tables and Wrapper are entities and JPQL is available. Again create a constructor for Wrapper but now wioth real types so no casting anymore

```
public Wrapper(Performance o1, Integer o2 ... ) { //means NOT varargs but as 
                                       //many args you need, all as real types they are
   this.performance = o1;
   this.id = o2;
   ...
}
```

Then it would be as easy as creating JPQL `TypedQuery` - for example - as

```
TypedQuery<Wrapper> tq = em.createQuery(
   " SELECT NEW Wrapper(E.Performance, E.id ...) FROM yourquerystuff "
   , Wrapper.class);
List<Wrapper> wrappers = tq.getResultList();
```